# Удаление кавычек в списке

Tags: python

Как из списка `l = ['0.14', '0.4348', '0.06']` удалить `' '` чтобы получить `l = [0.14, 0.4348, 0.06]`

Comment: При интерпретации показанного вами кода питоновый парсер не оставит в реальных объектах ни одной кавычки, а создаст список из трёх строк, внутри которых будут храниться только unicode-символы цифр и точек без кавычек. Поэтому ваш вопрос в текущем его виде не имеет смысла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Черточки это одинарные кавычки или апострофы. Ими описываются строковые литералы или просто строки

Лучше их не удалять, а преобразовать в числа, а именно в вещественные:

```
l = ['0.14', '0.4348', '0.06']
numbers = [float(x) for x in l]
print(numbers)
```

Или меняем текущий список, заменяя строки на числа:

```
l = ['0.14', '0.4348', '0.06']
for i in range(len(l)):
    l[i] = float(l[i])
print(l)
```

Результат:

```
[0.14, 0.4348, 0.06]
```